# Java WS application ignoring arguments sporadically

Tags: java, arguments, java-web-start

I have recently put together a JWS application which gets it's argument from a dynamically created JNLP file (details can be found [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=8396815)). It's all good except the application ignores the argument (starts without loading the specified number) on my system (linux x86_64). It seems however that the JWS application exactly as intended on the win_64 machine of a colleague of mine. This is rather interesting as I couldn't replicate his success on another similar win_64.

To make things more exciting, the same JWS application works just fine (in other words, doesn't ignore the argument) when I download the JNLP file and run it by javaws on the terminal.

I have compared the java.policy and javaws.policy files and there are no differences. The JNLP file clearly gives all-permissions, and the jar files are signed all fine (which can't be the source of the problem otherwise the application wouldn't start, right?).

***Question 1:** So what could this problem depend on?*

**EDIT:** I just managed to get proper response from a new (in this particular sense) win32 machine, without any obvious java update.  ***Question 2 :*** Is there a log file for javaws on which I can check what happens, or alternatively, can I verbose the launch to a console so I can create my own custom logs?

**Edit 2:** By the way, I have forgotten to mention that I have also posted this question at the [Oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1981494&tstart=0), which I should have perhaps mentioned initially as it was politely pointed out there.  Anyways, there is  more information on the JNLP file there on the thread, in case it might be relevant.

**Edit 3:** I came to think that the problem could be originating from the properties of the `<jnlp>` tag, upon generating the JNLP file. Originally the `jnlp` tag looked like this like this:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://mydomain/myapp/" 
    href="my.jnlp">
```

The problem with this is the fact that there is no my.jnlp in the the directory declared in the codebase, instead the JNLP code is created on the fly by a Perl script in the cgi-bin directory and returned as an output stream (I think). So I edited the script to generate the JNLP with the following tag:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://mydomain/myapp/" 
    href="http://mydomain/cgi-bin/my.jnlp">
```

The result of this experiment: not even the GUI started this time... 
I have found [a relevant thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1555521&tstart=0) on Oracle forums, where it was advised to define the `href` property in the following fashion:

```
href="script.jsp?<%=request.getQueryString()%>">
```

which unfortunately doesn't solve my problem.

***Question 3:*** Could this modification be applicable to my situation as well? In that case how? If not any insights on what might be causing the problem would be seriously appreciated as I am really at a stalemate on my work right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two weeks of wrestling with the JNLP file syntax and my CGI script, I think I finally found the crux of the problem. I am noting this down here (at the risk of looking pretentious enough to answer my own question) in case somebody else runs into the same problem.

The `href` property of the `<jnlp>` tag, in my case was apparently unnecessary and when removed the application started working as intended on both linux and win systems. I am not 100% sure if this is the exact reason but my understanding is that as the jnlp syntax is generated from a script and directly returned to the user instead of a jnlp file somewhere in the filesystem, the `href` property was pointing to a wrong place and perhaps caused some sort of a clash that is handled differently in different OS.

Comment: I had this problem for a couple of months. From time to time args were not being passed into the jar file. Finally this solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the JNLP file is not cached. I.e., each time you try something new, have you renamed / relocated the JNLP file?

---

Regarding your updates,
The only ting that comes to my mind is that you need to make sure that your script responds with the correct mime type: application/x-java-jnlp-file

That is, from your cgi-script, you have to provide the HTTP header field

```
Content-Type: application/x-java-jnlp-file
```

Comment: renaming is slightly problematic as the JNLP files are generated by a script, but I have tried to run the application on new computers (read: never been exposed to the application) and even restarted my browser/machine a couple of times. That should effectively empty the cache right?

Comment: Hmm.. yeah. Then it's really strange. You should do a minimal test-case that fails and post your specific OS / Java-version and example

Comment: yeah, the question is what constitutes a minimal-case scenario?

Comment: That's only possible for you to narrow down on.

Comment: I have created a test JNLP file which has a static argument and that seems to work fine, I believe there is a fundamental problem with how the JNLP is created by the script. I am suspecting the jnlp header now, I have mentioned it in edit3 above.

Comment: yep I think so: `print $q->header('application/x-java-jnlp-file');` or do I have to specifically mention `Content-Type:` as well?

Comment: Yeah, you do, have a look at the examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: hmm that doesn't change anything, same output.. Not that weird perhaps, as it does start the app but just ignores the argument, had it been a MIME problem it wouldnt have started the gui...

Comment: @aioobe: no problem, mate. I really appreciate you taking your time anyways.